# Why doesn't map (map f) x work in this case?

Tags: haskell

I recently tried this in Haskell:

```
> :t getEqs
getEqs :: [Char] -> [Char] -> ([Bool], [Bool])
> :t mixpairs
mixpairs :: [[[Char]]]
> :t map
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
> map (map getEqs) mixpairs
```

However, for seemingly no reason, it returned this:

```
<interactive>:38:1: error:
    • No instance for (Show ([Char] -> ([Bool], [Bool])))
        arising from a use of ‘print’
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
>
```

AFAICS what should happen is that a function that takes a list of lists and returns another thing is mapped over another list of lists of lists.
And it seems like that should work.

Comment: It does work.  You're not getting a type error in your expression.

Comment: Instead, try `> :t map (map getEqs) mixpairs` which will show that it works and give the resulting type. (Conversely, try just `> map` which will "fail" in the same way...)

Comment: Clarification: I should've typed "returned this:... ...instead of the intended [([Bool],[Bool])]".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems like that should work, and indeed it does work.

However, if you do this at the prompt, GHCi wants to *print out the result*, and that does *not* work, because the result is a list of functions, and functions can't be printed.

Comment: Yes, but (map getEqs) is of type [[Char]] -> ([Bool], [Bool]), so mapping it over [[[Char]]] should result in [([Bool],[Bool])], not a -> b or t (a -> b).

Comment: Why would `map getEqs` have type `[[Char]] -> ([Bool], [Bool])`? You forgot about the second `[Char]` argument of `getEqs`. (Besides – even if it had only one argument, `map getEqs` would have type `[[Char]] -> [([Bool], [Bool])]`).